# Trying to understand FormSet ManagementForm data (because error = "it's missing")

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to implement [Nicole Harris' example](http://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html) of formsets in my own project. Whereas she uses a formset to add a variable number of Links to a User profile, I'm trying to add a variable number of questions to a survey. My code is hence syntactically extremely similar (except I don't use a jquery plugin to dynamically add `<input>` fields to the webpage, I use my own javascript).

I'm getting a `ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with` error on form submission, at the line in my view where I try to call `survey_formset.is_valid()`. Here's the view:

```
def create_survey(request):
    #create the formset, specifying the form and formset we want to use
    SurveyFormSet = formset_factory(SurveyQuestionForm, 
                                        formset=BaseSurveyFormSet)  
    survey_formset = SurveyFormSet(request.POST)
    #THE BELOW CALL THROWS A VALIDATION ERROR: ManagementForm data missing... 
    if survey_formset.is_valid(): 
        print("survey_formset is valid!")
    else:
        print("survey_formset is invalid. Here are the errors:")
        for k, v in survey_form.errors.items():
            print(k, ": ", v)
```

Excuse the brevity; I don't really know what causes the error and I'm trying not to post tens of lines of irrelevant view/form code. I will add any additional code requested.

Including `{{ survey_formset.management_form }}` in the template doesn't make a difference.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform), the ManagementForm needs `form-TOTAL_FORMS`, `form-INITIAL_FORMS` and `form-MAX_NUM_FORMS`  . Nicole's code doesn't seem to have this except in the test code. However, if I just artificially inject it into the view with the below lines, it doesn't help (same error), so I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
data = {'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '1',
        'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0', 
        'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '' 
       }
survey_formset = SurveyFormSet(request.POST, data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you must include the management form inside the form tag your template if you are using a formset.

```
{{ survey_formset.management_form }}
```

Next, if you add forms to the formset or remove them, then you need to increment/decrement the value of the management form's `form-TOTAL_FORMS` input. The [django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) jQuery plugin takes care of doing this for you. If you don't use it, then you'll have to do this yourself.

Finally, this line does not make sense.

```
survey_formset = SurveyFormSet(request.POST, data)
```

The fields from the form data should be in `request.POST`, you can't add additional data with the second argument like that.

Comment: Thanks for your response Alasdair. I also read your other responses to the other FormSet questions. Sorry, I assumed that I could instantiate a FormSet with a variable number of *args, and the relevant ManagementForm data would appear. As it turns out, I'm an idiot and was looking so closely at the server-side code that I didn't notice that I didn't have `{{ survey_formset.management_form }}` between the `<form>` tags. Moving it allowed the necessary data to be passed in POST.